# CSS position relative creates white space below footer on change of height of div element

Tags: html, css, css-position

In the following code, I have created a skill graphic with the help of CSS `position: relative;`

However, if I want to shorten the height of the parent element like so:

```css
.skill-bars-r {
    height: 700px;
}
```

I get white space below the footer.

Here's the full [code](https://codepen.io/kasai-senshi/pen/RwbayrY)

The problem doesn't show up on Chrome, but it persists on Mozilla and Edge. Upon inspection, it appears that the issue is in the mentioned container, but there are no margins or paddings that could cause this issue.

I know that `position: relative` moves `item x` relatively to its parent, reserving its initial position upon movement, but I do not know how to fix this.

```css
.skills-circle-container {
    margin: 100px 0;
/*  fixed width to prevent graphic from resizing  */
    width: 700px;
    max-width: 700px;
/*     height: 700px;  */
/* ^ Results in white space below footer  */
}
```

I would like to shorten the height of `skill-bars-r` without the white space below the footer.

Comment: You are mistaking the behavior of position:relative. Itmoves things only visually, but each element still remains in its own used space. you can use negative margin to get things closer to each other, then flex and order can help if your structure doesn't fit entirely the visual ordering. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pozyLOM

Comment: @G-Cyr thank you, I realized I had switched the functionality of relative and absolute positioning and fixed it by switching them and adjusting the positioning like so: https://codepen.io/kasai-senshi/pen/JjPXpmP